# Ruby on Rails, SQL Server 2014

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

Our team is in the process of testing a Ruby on Rails application that is hosted on a Ubuntu Linux Server with the database hosted on a MS SQL Server 2008 R2 database server. We have built a test environment by performing a physical to VM on the Linux application server, and we have restored a copy of the production database on a SQL Server 2008 R2, and a SQL Server 2014 database instance (This is our target database server). We can make the necessary changes to the database.yml file, and get the application to communicate with the SQL Server 2008 R2 database. The problem arises when make the database.yml change to point to the SQL Server 2014 database. We get the following error:

> Error message:
>   Currently, only 2005, 2008, 2010, 2011, and 2012 are supported. We got back  Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) Apr 20 2015 17:29:27 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

I have tried a number of fixes without success.

```
ruby –v 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570 (x85_64-linux)
rails –v 3.2.18
gem –v 1.8.11
```

I installed several things:

```
sudo gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter
Bundle install 
/tmp Sudo touch restart.cmd

sudo gem install tiny_tds
sudo bundle install
/tmp Sudo touch restart.cmd
```

Now the application will not communicate with either of the SQL Server 2008 R2 or the SQL Server 20014 databases.

I am in the process of getting the VM application server restored to a previous state.